# Need help loading in a file that contains Strings and a Collection<String>?

Tags: java, methods, collections

I have two methods, one for writing information a textfile and one for reading in that same text file. I have the writing method working which writes various String objects and a Collection to the file. The problem comes when loading or reading the same file? I don't quite know how to read in the Collection of notes from the file? Here are both my methods.

```
public void writeDvd() throws DVDLibraryException {

    PrintWriter out;

    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(LIBRARY));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new DVDLibraryException("Problem writing to file", ex);
    }

    List<DVD> dvdList = this.returnListDvds();

    for (DVD currentDvd : dvdList) {
        out.print(currentDvd.getTitle() + DELIMETER
                + currentDvd.getReleaseDate() + DELIMETER
                + currentDvd.getRating() + DELIMETER
                + currentDvd.getDirectorsName() + DELIMETER
                + currentDvd.getStudio() + DELIMETER
                + currentDvd.getNotes());

        out.flush();
    }
    out.close();
}
```

And here is my loadDVD() method:

```
public void loadDvd() throws DVDLibraryException {

    Scanner sc;

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(LIBRARY)));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new DVDLibraryException("Could not read file", ex);
    }

    String currentLine;

    String[] currentTokens; 

    while (sc.hasNext()) {

        currentLine = sc.nextLine();
        currentTokens = currentLine.split(DELIMETER);

        DVD currentDvd = new DVD(currentTokens[0], currentTokens[1],
                currentTokens[2], currentTokens[3], currentTokens[4]);

        //I'm trying to do above with the currentTokens[5] for the Collection of Strings but not sure how to approach the problem?
        //This does not work
        //Collection<String> notes = currentDvd.getValuesNotes();
        //currentDvd.setValuesOfNotesForReading(notes);
        //String s = String.join(DELIMETER, notes);
        //currentDvd.setValuesOfNotesForReading(s);

        dvds.put(currentDvd.getTitle(), currentDvd);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DELIMITER` is not a newline and your intent is to write all the fields in one row, you seem to be missing an `out.println()` after the `out.print()`.

Comment: DELIMITER is just a String that is equal to two SemiColons :: which is what I want to separate all of my Strings I write to my file with. However my writeDvd method is not what is giving me problems as I see it writing correctly when I open the txt file. My problem lies in the loadDvd where I am tying to load along with the individual Strings of my DVD object, but a Collection<String> of notes associated with the DVD as well.